# Entity Framework 6 - trying to update few entities which has identical child entity in one transaction

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have a connection of one-to-many between entities X(one)<-->Y(many).
X is child of Y.
I have a method that gets Array of 'Y' and one 'X', and need to update all entities. -->  UpdateAll(List yList, X x)
I am using EF6 that connects to Oracle 11G.

Inside the transaction part, my code looks like that:

...

```
MyContext.X.Attach(x); 
MyContext.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified;
foreach(Y y in yList)
{
  MyContext.Y.Attach(y); 
  MyContext.Entry(y).State = EntityState.Modified;
}   
MyContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
MyContext.SaveChanges()
```

...

When running and trying to attach the first 'Y' im getting the following error:

```
'Attaching an entity of type 'X' failed because another entity of the same type 
already has the same primary key value'
```

Now, I managed to perform the update if first I set y.X to null.
I added this to the beginning of the method:

```
foreach(Y y in yList)
{
   y.X = null    
}
```

Is this the right way to perform the update?
Is their a better way?
Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't that imply, that an identical x already exists and you don't need to attach it? And when does that exception get thrown? While attaching `x` or while you attach an instance of `y`, which has an `x` ?

Comment: how does your models look? does `X` has collection of `Y`?

Comment: Yes, the entity X contains a collection of Y.
But in the method, X contains no Y, and Y contains one X

Comment: Marco, an identical X indeed exist in each Y.
Im getting the exception when attaching the first Y.